# Removing an anchor tag when uncheck a checkbox

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="checkbox" data-id="'+this.id+'"   
value=' + this.button_title + '   
name="showButton"   
class="switchery abc" data-size="sm" />

<div class="collectionAccountButtons"></div>
```

The Above checkbox is coming from **AJAX Response**. Now the following code does what i want but I want to remove the anchor tag if the checkbox is unchecked. when I do that it removes all of the anchor tag i want to remove a specific tag.

```
$('body').on('click', 'input[name="showButton"]', function () {  
        if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {  
              $('.collectionAccountButtons').append('<a href="' + $(this).attr('value') + '"  
              id="'+$(this).attr('data-id') +'" class="btn btn-block btn-warning">' +  
              $(this).attr('value') + '</a>');  
        }  
       else{
         $('.collectionAccountButtons a').remove();
        }
```

Actually the problem is that i'm unable to select the specific a tag inside .`collectinAccountButton` with id.

Comment: Where is `collectionAccountButtons` class. Show your HTML properly ?

Comment: Give a class to the a tag and query it using the same. Instead of trying to traverse.

Comment: @gkrthk the class will be same for all so will have no effect it will same as my code.

Comment: Remove next anchor tag `$(this).next('.collectionAccountButtons').find('a').remove();`

Comment: $('.collectionAccountButtons'). find ('a').remove()

Comment: @gkrthk I thinks it's remove all anchor tag which inside  `collectionAccountButtons` class so why I suggest `next` and `find` :)

Comment: @Shree the request doesn't explicitly state all a tags under the div. But if that's the case siblings can be used.

Comment: `$('.collectionAccountButton a[id=$(this).attr('data-id')]).remove()`
I've to achieve something like this but it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks folks I've find out the solution on my own.
`$('#' + $(this).attr('data-id')).remove();`